# Sending a model object and a binary stream in one multipart response

Tags: java, multipart, http-streaming

I´m currently recovering from a change in the company network configuration, which assassinated the file transfer in my document management application when users are connected via VPN. The communication between the rich client and my application server is implemented using Springs HttpInvoker, the file transfer used RMIIO. The RemoteInputStream was simply an attribute on my model object that represented the file I transfered.

So anyway, I have to replace RMIIO (DirectRemoteInputStream is not a solution here) and play around with plain HTTP streaming. I want to send a serialized model object and the binary data in a stream to the server, which works fine so far using a multipart request:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(...);

MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
InputStreamBody filePart = new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), "application/octet-stream", file.getName());
// this is my model object
byte[] serializedFileObject = serializeObject(fileObject);

multipartEntity.addPart("file", filePart);
multipartEntity.addPart("fileObject", new ByteArrayBody(serializedFileObject, "fileObject.ser"));
post.setEntity(multipartEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

Works fine and I can send model objects and binary data to the application server. But how would one do the opposite - return a model object and the binary data in one response? I read about multipart responses and how they can be consumed by several browsers, but how would one implement it with commons-httpclient - or even sweeter, using springs RestTemplate?